# Can I get cookie only from second level domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies

There are two domains:
  *a.example.com*
  *example.com*

*example.com* is the parent domain of *a.example.com*. Now both *a.example.com* and *example.com* may write a cookie named **test_cookie**. Now we have a page of *a.example.com* which will use javascript to read value of cookie **test_cookie**. Is there a way that only read the cookie set in the domain of *a.example.com* rather than *example.com*?

---

Maybe my question was a little unclear,

the goal i want to achieve is:
1. i want to write a function named **readCookie** to read the cookie with name **test_cookie** which:
    a. when there is a cookie: **test_cookie** under domain **example.com** and NO cookie **test_cookie** under domain **a.example.com**, readCookie returns null
    b. when there is a cookie: **test_cookie** under domain **example.com** AND ALSO a cookie **test_cookie** under domain **a.example.com**, readCookie returns the cookie value under domain **a.example.com**
    c. when there NO cookie: **test_cookie** under **exampler.com**, but there is a cookie **test_cookie** under domain **a.example.com**, readCookie returns the cookie value under domain **a.example.com**.

Answer (score 14):

That depends on how the cookie was defined, especially if the *Domain* attribute is specified what values it has (see [RFC 2965 – User Agent Role](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#section-3.3)):

- if *Domain* attribute is missing, the user agent assumes the current host; otherwise
- if *Domain* attribute is set, its value must start with a `.` like `.example.com` (if not, e.g. `example.com`, it will get changed by the user agent to `.example.com`).

Now the domain of a cookies must [*domain-match*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#section-1) the a domain to be send within the request. And that is the case:

- if either the domains are identical (in case the *Domain* parameter was missing), or
- if the value specified in the *Domain* attribute must be a suffix of the domain.

That means:

```
 effective domain | example.com | a.example.com | foo.example.com | bar.a.example.com
------------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------
      example.com |      ✓      |      ✗        |        ✗        |         ✗
    a.example.com |      ✗      |      ✓        |        ✗        |         ✗
     .example.com |      ✓      |      ✓        |        ✓        |         ✓
   .a.example.com |      ✗      |      ✓        |        ✗        |         ✓
```

So if you want a cookie to only be valid for *a.example.com*, you either omit the *Domain* attribute or you specify the *Domain* attribute with `.a.example.com` (that will make the cookie valid for *a.example.com* as well as its subdomains).

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to limit a cookie to `example.com`-only by setting the `domain` parameter. However, in most browsers, a cookie will default to `example.com`-only if no `domain` is supplied. Unfortunately in IE it defaults to allowing subdomains access to the cookie.

This is why you put your main site at `www.example.com` and not just `example.com`. With a site on the main domain `example.com` you cannot reliably keep your cookies separate.